# Unbound Value in recursive function ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to create a filter function which recieves a function as parameter and a list and returns another list with the filtering result.

```
let rec filter bool_func l r = 
    match l with
    | [] -> r
    | h::t -> if bool_func h then filter bool_func t (h::r)
    else filter bool_func t r in filter bool_func t [];;
```

Comment: Ok..? Do you have a question? You might want to have a look at [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword `in` goes with a previous `let` to make a local definition for use in the expression following `in`. So you have a local function definition of `filter` followed by the expression `filter bool_func t`. And indeed, outside the `let` there are no values (that you are showing us) named `bool_func` or `t`.